# .htaccess redirect all subdirectories except one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently in my .htaccess I have this code to redirect all requests to example.com/folder/ and all subdirectories to example.com/land.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder/(.+) page [L,R=301]
Redirect /folder https://example.com/land/
```

example.com/folder/ redirects to example.com/land - YES

example.com/folder/sub-a/ redirects to example.com/land - YES

Now I would like example.com/folder/sub-b/ and example.com/folder/sub-b/page not to redirect.

How can I achieve this? I have tried searching and reading, but have not found a solution that works for my situation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is this rule doing `RewriteRule ^folder/(.+) page [L,R=301]`?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure and not extremely familiar with .htaccess. I found it on a tutorial.

Comment: I think I need that because I am not redirecting example.com/folder/sub-a to example.com/land/sub-a - but rather example.com/folder/sub-a to example.com/land, but again I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect all.

And then redirect the one to its original location!

Comment: Well, the subdirectory that does not need redirecting will have extra parameters in the url, so I dont think that will work.